# Breaking Hexadecimal Value to multiple lines in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, hex

How do I break a long Hexadecimal Value in Coffeescript so that it spans multiple lines?

```
authKey = 0xe6b86ae8bdf696009c90e0e650a92c63d52a4b3232cca36e0ff2f5911e93bd0067df904dc21ba87d29c32bf17dc88da3cc20ba65c6c63f21eaab5bdb29036b83
```

to something like

```
authKey = 0xe6b86ae8bdf696009c90e0e650a92c63d52a4b323\
          2cca36e0ff2f5911e93bd0067df904dc21ba87d29c3\
          2bf17dc88da3cc20ba65c6c63f21eaab5bdb29036b83
```

Using **\** results in an *Unexpected 'NUMBER'* Error,
using **line break** in an *Unexpected 'INDENT'* Error

Comment: Why don't you store this in a string or a byte array?

Comment: True, that would work. I just want to know if it can be done in this notation.

Comment: Good point, thanks for explaining in your answer.

Comment: Good question; I looked for the lexical syntax [here](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/grammar.html) but didn't find anything precise.  The backslash at the end of line will give a space, though (try this inside a string literal) so your attempted assignment parses as `authKey = 123 456` which explains the "Unexpected NUMBER" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually no point in doing this in CoffeeScript because numbers are stored as 64-bit IEEE 754 values and you have too many bits of precision for the value to be stored as a number.

If you write

```
authKey = 0xe6b86ae8bdf696009c90e0e650a92c63d52a4b3232cca36e0ff2f5911e93bd0067df904dc21ba87d29c32bf17dc88da3cc20ba65c6c63f21eaab5bdb29036b83
console.log(authKey)
```

then the value logged is

```
1.2083806867379407e+154
```

You want to store your authKey as a string or byte array, both of which are trivial to write across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, this doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to be stored in a number, as opposed to a string; however, I decided to throw something together to allow it anyway:

```
stringToNumber = ( str ) -> parseInt( str.replace( /\n/g, '' ) )

authKey = stringToNumber """
  0xe6b86ae8bdf696009c90e0e650a92c63d52a4b323
  2cca36e0ff2f5911e93bd0067df904dc21ba87d29c3
  2bf17dc88da3cc20ba65c6c63f21eaab5bdb29036b83
"""
```

Like Ray said, this will just result in:

```
1.2083806867379407e+154
```